# Category Set language using simply typed lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, category-theory, types-and-programming-languages

I am currently self learning Category Theory and Simply typed lambda calculus (STLC).  For learning purposes, I have implemented an STLC interpreter as given in  *Types and Programming Languages book of Benjamin Pierce*. Now i am wondering if I can extend this interpreter with category of sets (category **Set** ). i.e. interpret expressions to construct sets, pushouts, pullbacks etc.

Unable to find any directions on how to do this. Can someone please provide any helpful suggestions on this?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two directions in which you can proceed.

First, [Church's simple type theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-church/) (see also [this explanation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/#SimpTypeTheoLCalc)) extends the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus with the types of natural numbers and booleans, and other constructs that make it sufficiently expressive to encode a certain kind of classical set theory. These ideas were pursued in the [HOL theorem provers](https://hol-theorem-prover.org). For instance, [HOL light](https://github.com/jrh13/hol-light/) for a small implementation. This approach has the flavor of doing *logic*, i.e., there is no general notion of computation - as opposed to the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus, which is a programming language.

Second, [dependent type theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory/), of which there are many variants, is also an extension of the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus. It can be used as a foundation of mathematics. They are used in proof assistants, such as [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr), [Agda](https://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), and [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io). Some variants, notably Martin-Löf type theory, do retain the character of a programming language. In fact, [Idris](https://www.idris-lang.org) is a programming language based on dependent type theory.

None of the above is "set theory", but these formalisms are quite suitable for expressing mathematics, including category theory.